# How do i strip whole script sections with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

if i have a string like

```
<p>this is some content</p><script>alert('hello');</script>
```

i want to get the string without any scripts, but with the formatting, how do i do it?

```
<p>this is some content</p>
```

i tried

```
var html = "<p>etc</p><script>alert('hello world');</script>".replace("<script*</script>", "p");
```

but that gave me something like

```
".replace("", "p"); $('#blogDescription').html(html); }); });
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right string? Looks like you had something else on the clipboard :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without using regex, by using some DOM manipulation you can run through each of the elements in the DOM fragment created from the string and remove the `script` tags.

```
var html = "<p>etc</p><script>alert('hello world');</script>";

var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;

function stripScript(parent){
  var elements = parent.children;

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].nodeName === 'SCRIPT'){
      parent.removeChild(elements[i]);
    } else if(elements[i].children.length > 0){
      stripScript(elements[i]);
    }
  }
}

stripScript(container);

console.log(container.innerHTML);
```

Or with jQuery

```
var html = "<p>etc</p><script>alert('hello world');</script>";

container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;
$(container).find('script').remove();

console.log(container.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "<p>etc</p><script>alert('hello world');</script>".replace("<script>").replace("</script>");
```